# In Death Stranding, how to make bridge link with my PSN friend whom I haven't met in the game?

Tags: death-stranding

In Death Stranding me and my friend have PSN accounts in different regions. I've never seen him among the people I interact with during the game. Is there some way to force us to connect? I understand that the game picks objects and items and people according to its own hidden logic, but I still hope for some way to play and explore together.

Comment: can try going to the same location, placing signs there and then shouting? this should work if you are on the same server

Comment: That's the thing - how can we find out or force the game to put us on the same server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no current way to force any other player into your game world server.**

The only option is to keep reloading the game in hopes you eventually meet, which just isnt practical.

As a side note, should you ever see their name on your Bridge Links list, you can enter into a Strand Contract with them and ensure their structures are always in your game world.